# Adding object to session thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp

Is the adding object to session threadsafe?

in my jsp file, i am checking if session doesn't contain my object then i fetch if from the DB and put it in session.

Is this operation thread safe(in case multiple requests get to same line of code at the same time)?

Comment: No, But you can make it by adding Serialization and Synchronization

Comment: The `Session` itself and its context manager are not thread-safe, you need to utilize a session scooped class, and put the business inside a synchronized method.

Comment: But what is the scenario that can break anything when 2 threads try to put object to session?

Answer (score 0):

The access to [HttpSession](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) attributes is not thread safe. Multiple servlets executing request threads may have active access to the same session object at the same time.

The Developer has the responsibility for threadsafe access to the attribute objects themselves. You can synchronize on the `session` object to get/set attributes to it:

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
synchronized(session)
{
//get/set attributes to session object
}
```

Comment: But session is "per user" meaning each user will get his own session object, it's not correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct. But the same user can open multiple browsers (window tabs) and send requests. In this case, for the same user, multiple requests can come in to the servlets and when you do `HttpSession session=request.getSession();`, the same session instance is available in multiple threads. So if you don't synchronize on session, one thread may unknowingly override values placed by another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is a single session (for a user or connectivity) based on the sessionId, any number of concurrent requests can be initiated from that user within a given session. For example, a user may be loading this same JSP file that you have written code to add an object from DB to session.

Following is an example code to denote what you might be writing.

```
object = session.getAttribute("key");
if (object == null) {
   object = getObjectFromDB();
   session.setAttribute("key", object);
}
```

Since thread switching can happen at any line of the above code segment, there is a possibility that multiple threads noticing the `object` as `null` and trying to put the object into session. Since each invocation of `session.setAttribute(key,value)` with the same key overrides the existing value, there will not be an error thrown.

However you will have to consider your business requirement and see whether invoking `getObjectFromDB()` multiple times unnecessarily is causing issues to the business expectations.